# Downgrade Amazon RDS Multi AZ deployment to Standard Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-backups, amazon-rds

What might happen if I downgrade my Multi AZ deployment to standard deployment? Is there any possibility of i/o freeze or data loss? if yes, what might be the proper way to minimize downtime of data availability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have tried downgrading from Multi AZ deployment to a standard deployment.
The entire process took around 2-3 minutes (The transition time should depend upon your database size). The transition was seamless. We did not experience any downtime. Our website was working as expected during this period.

Just to ensure that nothing gets affected, I took a snapshot and a manual data base dump before downgrading.

Hope this helps.